# How to save multi images into database in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to upload more than one image into database, i've created the form and am getting all the images uploaded perfectly .

In my views i've created a `list` to contain all the images, If i saved the list inside database in **images** column, am getting a dictionary rather than a list contains all the images one by one like this:

`{u'123.jpg',u'123.jpg',u'123.jpg'}`

**the problem** is if i want to fetch them by index am getting letters rather than the values .

Another way , i created another `dict` so i can get them by key or by value , but when they get saved inside database this error raising:

`ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict'`

Here is the codes:

```
@master_route.route('/product/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def index():

    form = AddProduct()
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()
    imagesList = []

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'image[]' in request.files:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            product = Goods()
            file = request.files.getlist("image[]")
            for zipfile in file:
                filename = zipfile.filename.split('/')[0]
                zipfile.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename))
                imagesList.append(filename)

            product.images = imagesList[]
            db.session.add(product)
            db.session.commit()

            flash('Images Uploaded', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('master.index'))

    else:
        return render_template('add-product.html', form=form)
    return render_template('add-product.html', form=form, action='add')
```

Is there any way to save them as a list so i can get them by index, or as a dictionary, please any help ??

### **Update**

I can solve the problem by creating columns for each image and fetching each one by index then committing it to database, but am trying as much as possible to DRY my code !!

**Model**

```
class Goods(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    product_name = db.Column(db.String())
    sizes = db.Column(db.String())
    hex_color = db.Column(db.String())
    text_color = db.Column(db.String(), server_default='white')
    tkan = db.Column(db.String())
    description = db.Column(db.Text())
    ordered = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=0)
    viewed = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=0)
    published = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    article = db.Column(db.Integer(), server_default='12345')
    age = db.Column(db.String())
    slug = db.Column(db.String())
    price = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=1000)

    images = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True)
    # image1 = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True, server_default='404')
    # image2 = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True, server_default='404')
    # image3 = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True, server_default='404')
    # image4 = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True, server_default='404')
    # image5 = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True, server_default='404')

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    cat_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    sub_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sub.id'))
    # subs = db.relationship('Sub', backref='user', lazy='dynamic', passive_deletes=True)
    # categories = db.relationship('Category', backref='user', lazy='dynamic', passive_deletes=True)
    comments = db.relationship('Comments', backref='goods', lazy='dynamic', passive_deletes=True)

    def slug_this(self, value):
        self.slug = slugify(value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Product: {}".format(self.product_name)
```

Comment: Any suggestions guys !!

Comment: Can you show the code of model define?

Comment: Yes, you can find it in the **Updates** .

Comment: You can try `json` column type in postgresql. Or you can save the list string representation to image field. when you select them you can use `eval()` to translate the string to list.

Comment: Could you please explain in more details ?? , do you mean by `json` to make a serializer for the images ??

Comment: I did tried to convert them into list but inside the database am getting a **set** not a **list** !! , i tried this : product.images = list(imagesList[])

Comment: There is a field type like `Integer`, `String` named `json`(`jsonb`) in postgresql. Follow this [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html)

Comment: You define the images field to String type. Use `product.images = str(imagesList)` to store the string representation to the db.

Comment: i tried that, inside the database am getting them as a string list, so if i want to fetch them by index inside a `for` loop am getting a loop of letters which are the images,  it won't work, now this what it looks like inside database:
`u"[u'1376606916.png', u'avatar3.png', u'beard_avatar.png', u'etikhacker.png', u'photo.jpg']"`

Comment: Inside the shell the **product.images** returns the list as a unicode u"" !!

Answer (score 0):

The problem get solved, what @stamaimer mentioned is that i need to convert the **imageList** to a string list, i did that literally, when the list get saved inside database , the list get converted to a `unicode` list, to solve this problem i should have used the `eval()` function to convert them to a list .

Now every thing works just fine :| , thanks @stamaimer .