# how to upload multiple images to python-sqlachemy database?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to upload multiple images to sqlalchemy database using flask-wtf forms. In my form one user can have multiple items and those items can have multiple photos so i use 'one to many relationships' If i use one image everything works ok with this example, since sqlalchemy doesn't support list as value i dont know what to do.

```
image1 = None
@app.route("/app_main_page/prekes/ceate",  methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def CreatePrekes():
    global image1
    form = UpdateItemForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.prekes_nuotrauka.data:
            for prekes_nuotrauka in form.prekes_nuotrauka.data:
                file = save_pict(prekes_nuotrauka)
                image1 = url_for('static', filename='profile_pictures/' + file)
            post = Preke(pavadinimas=form.pavadinimas.data, apibudinimas=form.apibudinimas.data,
                        prekes_nuotrauka=image1, author=current_user)
            db.session.add(post)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Your post have been created", "success")
            return redirect(url_for("visos_prekes"))
    return render_template("CreatePrekes.html", title="New Post", form=form)
```

```
class UpdateItemForm(FlaskForm):
    pavadinimas = StringField("Pavadinimas", validators=[DataRequired()])
    apibudinimas = TextAreaField("Apibudinimas", validators=[DataRequired()])
    prekes_nuotrauka = MultipleFileField("Prekes nuotrauka", validators=[FileAllowed(["jpeg", "png", "jpg"])])
    submit = SubmitField("Sukurti")
```

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    picture = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default.jpeg")
    creation_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    item = db.relationship("Preke", backref="author", lazy=True, uselist=True)

class Preke(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    pavadinimas = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    apibudinimas = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    prekes_nuotrauka = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default.jpeg")
    creation_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [`image_attachement()`](https://sqlalchemy-imageattach.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/) which provides `uselist=True`.

Another way would be to save the images in a folder and have a list containing strings with the paths to the images. Like this: [How to save multi images into database in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315641/how-to-save-multi-images-into-database-in-flask)